# How to combine two files into a third using only linux system calls?

Tags: c, linux

I am a complete noob when it comes to linux system calls interacting with c-code.
So far I have been able to open a single file, but that's about it. I'm unsure of how I would take a second file and combine both of those into a third.

For example, I have file1 with simple text contents, and file2 with the same, how could I combine both contents into file3 using only linux system calls? I know I have to use `lseek` to change the pointer, but unsure of how to utilize that.

here is what I have so far... I apologize for the scarcity:

*This takes file1 and copies it to file2, I believe*

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int copyfile(const char *file1, const char *file2)
{
    int infile, outfile;
    ssize_t nread;
    char buffer[BUFSIZE]

    if( (infile = open(file1, O_RDONLY)) == -1 )
        return (-1);

    if( (infile = open(file2, O_WRONLY|O_CREATE|O_TRUNC, PERM)) == -1 )
    {
        close (infile);
        return (-2);
    }

    /*read from file1 BUFSIZE chars at a time*/
    while ( nread = read (infile, buffer, BUFSIZE) )
    {
        // write buffer to output file
        if (write (outfile, buffer, nread) < nread)
        {
            close(infile);
            close(outfile);
            return (-3);
        }
    }
    close (infile)
    close (outfile)

    if (nread == -1)
        return (-4);
    else
        return(0);
}
```

The files will be entered within the terminal as such:

`lastnameCat.c file1 file2 file3`

such that file1 and file2 are added together, and sent into file3.

Comment: Just FYI, you could cheat and do `system("cat file1 file2 > file3");`. Or just do it from linux shell instead of writing a C program.

Comment: Note:`read()` can return -1. Deal with it!

Comment: @Gillespie I would love to do that, but unfortunately they want a program they can execute multiple times a day for someone who doesn't know how to run the terminal

Comment: Please always try to indent your code properly, it makes it much easier to follow and to find bugs.

Comment: @Graeme my apologies, and thank you to John Kugelman for properly indenting for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `copy_file_range` system call for this. It is faster than using `read` and `write` calls as the copying is done inside the kernel. From the [`man`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) page:

> The  copy_file_range() system call performs an in-kernel copy between two file descriptors without the additional cost of transferring data from the kernel to user space and then back into the kernel.

Here is an example of using it:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int do_copy(int infd, int outfd)
{
    ssize_t bytes = 0;
    do
    {
        bytes = copy_file_range(infd, NULL, outfd, NULL, SSIZE_MAX, 0);
    }
    while(SSIZE_MAX == bytes);

    return bytes;
}

int concatenate(const char *inpath1, const char *inpath2, const char *outpath)
{
    int infd1 = -1;
    int infd2 = -1;
    int outfd = -1;
    int res = -1;

    infd1 = open(inpath1, O_RDONLY);
    if(infd1 < 0)
        goto close;

    infd2 = open(inpath2, O_RDONLY);
    if(infd2 < 0)
        goto close;

    outfd = open(outpath, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC);
    if(outfd < 0)
        goto close;

    res = do_copy(infd1, outfd);
    if(res < 0)
        goto close;

    res = do_copy(infd2, outfd);

close:
    if(infd1 >= 0)
        close(infd1);

    if(infd2 >= 0)
        close(infd2);

    if(outfd >= 0)
        close(outfd);

    return res;
}
```

The loop in `do_copy` allows for very large files which may exceed the maximum copy possible in a single call.

Comment: Thank you @Graeme but I am getting this error upon attempting to compile 

`gcc lastnameCAT.c -o lastnameCAT
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @user7823016, this is not a full program. The reason you are getting the error is because it doesn't have a `main` function. You have to write that yourself. This is just an example of how to do the actual copying part.

Comment: oh of course, do you think what I have in my submission would be enough (with enough tweaking) as a main function?

Comment: @user7823016, well I don't see any actual file names anywhere... Where do they come from? Command line arguments? `scanf`? Hardcoded?

Comment: command line arguments. So it would look like this:

`lastnameCAT.c file1 file2 file3`
I'm only an intern, but they asked that it be in this format for now and I will change it later

Comment: Well, plenty of tutorials out there on how to use command line arguments in C. Sure there are lots related questions already with answers on SO too All you need to do is pass your file names to `concatenate`. Really doesn't get much simpler than that.

Comment: thank you for all of your help . I'm honestly not even sure what I would look for, to ensure that it would work with your functions. Is there any way you would consider showing me an approximate main method? If not, I completely understand, and thank you for all you've done.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, it sounds like this doesn't *have* to be a C program as long as it is user friendly. As long as you can guarantee that it will be run in linux, just create a shell script and name it whatever you want. You could even give the shell script the same name as your c program executable and users wouldn't be able to tell the difference:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat $1 $2 > $3
```

Say that you name this script `lastnameCat` and make it executable with `chmod +x ./lastnameCat`. From then on you could simply do:

```
$ ./lastnameCat file1 file2 file3
```

You *could* also name this script `lastnameCat.c` if you wanted, but that is a bit deceptive in my opinion since it is not a C file, it is a bash script.